# output_notebook() is not defined - why?

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, bokeh

Trying Bokeh for the first time. Using the following example code from http://docs.bokeh.org:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

from bokeh.charts import Scatter
from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers

output_notebook()
```

Inside iPython (Anaconda, py 3.4, Win 7), get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-c57c6fa8f51a> in <module>()
----> 1 output_notebook()

NameError: name 'output_notebook' is not defined
```

Why? This is straight from the examples.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks as if you forgot to import `output_notebook`.

Typical notebooks have following imports:

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_notebook()
```